# how to use addr2line in commandline

Tags: c++, linux

how to use addr2line?
i have a program that gives the backtrace of last 10 addresses that it visited before crash. but if i use these address to addr2line like

```
addr2line -e test [address]
```

it just gives me

```
??:0
```

is there a special way to compile to use addr2line like we use ggdb to use gdb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have some debugging information compiled in to your executable. e.g.

```
$ gcc t.c                         # debug information not requested
$ gdb ./a.out 
...
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400588
(gdb) q
$ addr2line -e a.out 0x400588
??:0                              # no information returned

$ gcc -g t.c                      # default debug information requested with -g
$ addr2line -e a.out 0x400588    
t.c:4                             # line information returnedd
$
```