# Is there a way to avoid that addr2line prints "question marks" lines

Tags: linux, addr2line

When I call `addr2line` on my program, I get an output of this form :

```
??
??:0
??
??:0
BdmLsim3::InitPopulation() at bdmLsim3/../src/Spatial/BdmLsim3.cpp:634
BdmLsim3::InitSimulation() at bdmLsim3/../src/Spatial/BdmLsim3.cpp:1012
```

Is there a possibility to get a cleaner output (without question marks and zero lines - `??` and `??:0`) ? Another tool that can resolve addresses and is a bit more configurable ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use addr2line in commandline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015769/how-to-use-addr2line-in-commandline)